# Bootable Flash Drive Ubuntu Install

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, 64-bit, usb-drive

Just to ask if the method shown here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
Allows a computer to be installed with 64-bit Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu on one of my computers, however it only installed 32-bit Ubuntu. (The computer has 4GB RAM)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This  [*method*](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) of creating bootable Ubuntu flash drive on Windows was applicable for both 32 and 64 bit Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a 64-bit or a 32-bit version of Ubuntu following the ISO you downloaded; the USB installation has nothing to do with it. Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and then choose your flavour, i.e, 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: Yes but using the method Ubuntu recommends to create a bootable flash drive, as the link hows, I just wondered if the application you have to install downloads a 32/64 bit installer onto the flash drive. Or if the flash drive is able to install both 32 bit and 64 bit Ubuntu onto a system

Comment: Oh... Sorry, I don't know that, I always choose the ISO and it's architecture on ubuntu's official website. As far as I know, Ubuntu is not multi-arch, but I may be wrong. 
You could maybe look at the ISO size, it should be more than 1GB if it is multi-arch, and less than 1GB if it is only build for one architecture.

2GB or larger USB flash drive (fat32 formatted) is required following pendrive's documentation, so it suggest that it could be multi-arch. I can't help you further.